# How to use curl in Queue with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using queue for the first time in Laravel.
I can't seem to get it work. I am sending an email and also calling a url with curl ().

I have even tried file_content_get(), yet it doesn't seem to work. The email seems to work just fine...

My question is: is there a different approach to calling an endpoint using Queue?

```php
public function handle()
{
    $email = new Airtime();
    $ch = curl_init("some-url");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // exec($ch);
    curl_exec($ch);
    Mail::to($this->details['email'])->send($email);
}
```

The email gets sent, but the curl is completely ignored.

Comment: _I can't seem to get it work_ Thats not a great description of your problem. Show us code and errors or at least a better problem statement than this

Comment: I have added code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the function is disabled in php.ini in `disable_functions` directive or something blocks your requests on the network level, there is no specific reason this should not be executed. Are you sure that the endpoint being called did not in fact receive the request?

Calling remote endpoints from queues works fine for me. I just tested it now with a snippet below:

```
 /**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $result = \Http::get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')->json('entries');
    \Log::info($result);
}
```

Result:

```
    [2022-10-01 11:12:25] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'API' => 'AdoptAPet',
    'Description' => 'Resource to help get pets adopted',
    'Auth' => 'apiKey',
    'HTTPS' => true,
    'Cors' => 'yes',
    'Link' => 'https://www.adoptapet.com/public/apis/pet_list.html',
    'Category' => 'Animals',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'API' => 'Axolotl',
    'Description' => 'Collection of axolotl pictures and facts',
    'Auth' => '',
    'HTTPS' => true,
    'Cors' => 'no',
    'Link' => 'https://theaxolotlapi.netlify.app/',
    'Category' => 'Animals',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'API' => 'Cat Facts',
    'Description' => 'Daily cat facts',
    'Auth' => '',
    'HTTPS' => true,
    'Cors' => 'no',
    'Link' => 'https://alexwohlbruck.github.io/cat-facts/',
    'Category' => 'Animals',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'API' => 'Cataas',
    'Description' => 'Cat as a service (cats pictures and gifs)',
    'Auth' => '',
    'HTTPS' => true,
    'Cors' => 'no',
    'Link' => 'https://cataas.com/',
    'Category' => 'Animals',
  )
```